# Linear span of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I'm looking for a way to generate the spans of a given vector in MATLAB.

For example:

if `a = [ 0 1 0 1]` I need all vectors of the form `[0 x 0 y]`, 1 <= x <= max1, 1 <= y <= max2,.

or if

`a = [ 0 1 0 1 1 0]` I need all vectors of the form `[0 x 0 y z 0]`, 1 <= x <= max1, 1 <= y <= max2, 1<= z <= max3.

Note that the vector can have a variable number of 1's.

My first impression is that I would need a variable number of for loops, though I don't know if that is doable in MATLAB. Also any other ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple for loops for this. The code below generates all required vectors as rows of a tall matrix. It actually creates the *columns* of the matrix one at a time. Each column will have numbers 1:m(i) arranged in the pattern where

- each term repeats the number of times equal to the product of all m-numbers after m(i)
- the whole pattern repeats the number of times equal to the product of all m-numbers before m(i)

This is what `repmat(kron(1:m(i),ones(1,after)),1,before)'` does. (Starting with R2015a you can use `repelem` to simplify this by replacing the `kron` command, but I don't have that release yet.)

```
a = [0 1 0 1 1 0];
m = [2 4 3];        // the numbers max1, max2, max3 
A = zeros(prod(m), length(a));
i = 1;                           // runs through elements of m 
for j=1:length(a)                // runs through elements of a 
    if (a(j)>0)
        before = prod(m(1:i-1));
        after = prod(m(i+1:end));
        A(:,j) = repmat(kron(1:m(i),ones(1,after)),1,before)';
        i = i+1;
    end
end
```

Output:

```
 0     1     0     1     1     0
 0     1     0     1     2     0
 0     1     0     1     3     0
 0     1     0     2     1     0
 0     1     0     2     2     0
 0     1     0     2     3     0
 0     1     0     3     1     0
 0     1     0     3     2     0
 0     1     0     3     3     0
 0     1     0     4     1     0
 0     1     0     4     2     0
 0     1     0     4     3     0
 0     2     0     1     1     0
 0     2     0     1     2     0
 0     2     0     1     3     0
 0     2     0     2     1     0
 0     2     0     2     2     0
 0     2     0     2     3     0
 0     2     0     3     1     0
 0     2     0     3     2     0
 0     2     0     3     3     0
 0     2     0     4     1     0
 0     2     0     4     2     0
 0     2     0     4     3     0
```

Comment: Hi! I've made a chatroom for us so we can discuss things related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or spans longer than what can be placed in a comments box.  Come visit when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab